# How to find out which polygon contains the most points using Python OGR?

Tags: python, ogr

I have two shapefiles: point (railway stations) and polygon (regions). My task is to write a script using OGR module in Python that can determine in which region the biggest amount of railway stations is.

I don't have any problem loading shp and reading its content, it's just the mechanics of solving the task that I can't seem to figure out.

I thought if I iterate over the regions (kind of abusing SetAttributeFilter), get their geometry, then in another loop get geometry of the points and finally do intersect (or maybe within, I am not sure, seemed to un/work the same), I get the result but I must be doing something wrong. Funny thing is, the first result I get is correct but following on it doesn't work as expected.

You can check the crucial part of my code (until here it works fine), I am a beginner so it may be ugly.

```
filters = []

for code in codes:
    filter1 = str("KOD_KRAJ='" + code + "'")
    filter2 = str('"'+filter1+'"')
    filters.append(filter2)

stations = 0

for filter in filters:
    regions.SetAttributeFilter(filter)

    for i in range(0,numberRe):
        regionFeat = regions.GetNextFeature()
        regionGeometry = regionFeat.GetGeometryRef()

        for r in range(0,numberRa):
            railwayFeature = railway.GetFeature(r)
            railwayGeometry = railwayFeature.GetGeometryRef()

            if railwayGeometry.Within(regionGeometry):
                stations = stations + 1
        print filter, str(stations)
```

Note: KOD_KRAJ is the header in shapefile's attribute table and variable "codes" is a list containing its instances (administrative code of each region). SetAttributeFilter should be used like this ("NAME='something'") which is why the weird first loop.

I just want to get it working to the stage when I get the numbers for each region, after that it will not be hard for me to do the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix  `GetNextFeature()` and a for loop (look at [Python GDAL/OGR: retrieved feature is NoneType](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65847/2581))

The solution is

```
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()): #no need of range(0,layer.GetFeatureCount())
    regionFeat = layer.GetFeature(i)
    regionGeometry = regionFeat.geometry()
```

And you cannot use directly nested loops with OGR (look at [Python-OGR: nested loop only loops once](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76683/python-ogr-nested-loop-only-loops-once))

[image]

```
from osgeo import ogr
poly = ogr.Open("poly_stack.shp")
polys = poly.GetLayer()
point = ogr.Open("pt_stack.shp")
points = point.GetLayer()
```

If I directly use a nested loop

```
tot = {}
for i, pol in enumerate(polys):
     #iterate through polygons
     pol_geom = pol.geometry()
     tot[i] = 0
     for j, pt in enumerate(points):
         #iterate through points
         point_geom = pt.geometry()
         if pol_geom.Contains(point_geom):
             tot[i]= tot[i] + 1
 print tot         
 {0: 3, 1: 0, 2: 0}
```

Only the first loop of points is taken into consideration and you cannot use `points.ResetReading()` at the end of the loop

If you want only the biggest amount of points in polygons, you can use the `Clone()` function of OGR ([ogr: what is the advantage of using `geom.Clone()` over `geom`?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168975/2581))

Make a list of the geometries

```
pol_geoms =[pol.geometry().Clone() for pol in polys]
point_geoms = [pt.geometry().Clone()  for pt in points]
```

Now you can use a nested loop:

```
tot = {}
#iterate through polygons
for i, pol in enumerate(pol_geoms):
    tot[i] = 0
    for j, pt in enumerate(point_geoms):
         #iterate through points
         if pol.Contains(pt):
             tot[i]= tot[i] + 1
print tot         
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 6}
```

I use here the enumerate function because you can find the original features

But it is much easier with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) ([More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc (1)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066/2581) or [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) ([More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc (2)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc/165413#165413)