# Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS

Tags: python, shapefile, python-2.7, shapely, fiona

I want to follow that post [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102933/more-efficient-spatial-join-in-python-without-qgis-arcgis-postgis-etc)

My target is to count points in polygons and export to new shapefiles the polygons that have a specific number of points on the count or score.

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
polygons = [pol for pol in fiona.open('poly.shp')]
points = [pt for pt in fiona.open('point.shp')]
# attributes of the polygons
for poly in polygons:
   print poly['properties']
for pt in points:
    print i['properties']
for i, pt in enumerate(points):
     point = shape(pt['geometry'])
     #iterate through polygons
     for j, poly in enumerate(polygons):
        if point.within(shape(poly['geometry'])):
             # sum of attributes values
             polygons[j]['properties']['score'] = polygons[j]['properties']['score'] + points[i]['properties']['score']
```

If I run this code with my shapefiles I take  `keyerror 'score'`, that is because on my files I don't have a score field.

How to fix that without changing my schema from the input shapefiles?

I don't want to import new field in my files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The script is for a specific shapefile with a score field. In your case, why not simply use a dictionary of polygons as in [How to find out which polygon contains the most points using Python OGR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222945/2581)

[image]

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
polygons = [pol for pol in fiona.open('polys.shp')]
points = [pt for pt in fiona.open('points.shp')]

 totpts = {}
 for i, poly in enumerate(polygons) :
     totpts[i] = 0
     for j, pt in enumerate(points):
           point = shape(pt['geometry'])
           if shape(poly['geometry']).contains(point):
               totpts[i] += 1

print totpts
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 6}
```

If you open the polygons shapefile now

```
polys = fiona.open('polys.shp')
# show the third polygon
polys[totpts.keys()[2]]
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(151.05805243445693, -185.31460674157304), (167.9943820224719, -167.48689138576782), (215.68352059925093, -180.85767790262173), (251.33895131086143, -218.29588014981277), (249.11048689138573, -244.14606741573033), (189.83333333333331, -253.95131086142322), (144.37265917602994, -221.8614232209738), (151.05805243445693, -185.31460674157304)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '2', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 3)])}
```